# Newtonsoft.Json ContractResolver CreateProperty provides wrong ReflectedType on MemberInfo?

Tags: c#, json.net

Using a custom ContractResolver based on `DefaultContractResolver` that overwrites `CreateProperty` I want to use the type of the object that is being serialized. This should be in the `MemberInfo.ReflectedType` property but Newtonsoft.Json seems to provide the base class instead:

```cs
    abstract class A
    {
        public string A1 { get; set; }

    }

    class B : A
    {
        public string B1 { get; set; }
    }

    class MyResolver : DefaultContractResolver
    {
        protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{member}: {member.ReflectedType.Name}");
            return base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);
        }
    }
```

When using the Serializer like so:

```cs
var token = JToken.FromObject(new B(), JsonSerializer.CreateDefault(new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = new MyResolver() }));
```

How do I get `typeof(B)` for both properties?

Comment: This seems to be intentional.  In [`ReflectionUtils.GetProperties(Type targetType, BindingFlags bindingAttr)`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/52190a3a3de6ef9a556583cbcb2381073e7197bc/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Utilities/ReflectionUtils.cs#L940) there is a comment *a base class private getter/setter will be inaccessible unless the property was gotten from the base class*, then the code proceeds to get the `MemberInfo` of the declaring type rather than the reflected type.

Comment: As a workaround, override [`DefaultContractResolver.CreateProperties()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_DefaultContractResolver_CreateProperties.htm) instead, and make any necessary changes there.  The `Type type` argument is the actual reflected type.

Comment: Can you provide more details about what you actually need to do in `CreateProperty()`?  Or Should I make that an answer?

Comment: @dbc I see but that doesn't make sense for public properties. If you could put both of your comments into an answer then I'd accept it.